# AngularJS next view not working

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui

We are currently learning/using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and have hit a brick wall, we want to be able to change the form view using the next and previous buttons. So we are able to fill in each section/stage of the form individually.

We have currently got the first form fields 'packingtest' displaying without any issues but we are unable to click/view the next set of fields.

If anyone could advice please let us know where we are going wrong.

Thank you.

Our [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TRoz9MVnfpJhk5qOyNIY?p=preview) Code

[image: Step One]
[image: Step Two]

```
// WarrantyForm
.state('warrantyForm', {
  url: '^/warrantyForm/:jobID',
  controller: 'warrantyFormController',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'warranty/form.html',
    },
    'warrantyForm@warrantyForm': {
      templateUrl: 'warranty/forms/packingtest.html'
    }
  }

})
.state('warrantyForm.usagetest', {
  url: '^/warrantyForm/:jobID/usagetest',
  templateUrl: 'warranty/forms/usagetest.html'
})
.state('warrantyForm.visualtest', {
   url: '^/warrantyForm/:jobID/visualtest',
   templateUrl: 'warranty/forms/visualtest.html' 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [UI-Routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) it was clear where we was going wrong. These are our updated snippets below. I really do suggest looking into [UI-Routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) if anyone else has similar problems.

**JS**

```
// Form
.state('home.warrantyform', {
  url: '^/warranty/forms/:jobID',
  templateUrl: 'user/warranty/forms/index.html'
})
// Form, Packing Test
.state('home.warrantyform.packingtest', {
  url: '^/warranty/forms/packingtest/:jobID',
  templateUrl: 'user/warranty/forms/packing-test.html'
})
// Form, Usage Test
.state('home.warrantyform.usagetest', {
  url: '^/warranty/forms/usagetest/:jobID',
  templateUrl: 'user/warranty/forms/usage-test.html'
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a ui-sref="home.warrantyform.packingtest" class="btn button">Previous</a>
<a ui-sref="home.warrantyform.usagetest" class="btn button">Next</a>
```